# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04: unified panel sliders

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome (version 3.10) and I seem to be missing certain items in the unified panel like the brightness slider, wired connection status, bluetooth status and battery status when charged. There is only a volume slider, Wifi status and the username. Is anyone else having this problem or is it a problem with my configuration? I've read somewhere that this has something to do with gnome-settings-daemon being version 3.8. If this is the problem is there anything I can do or do I wait till 14.10?

Comment: bluetooth as well - i'm using 3.8 where possible.